# Laravel: test response is different from real response

Tags: laravel, phpunit

In a Laravel9 project:

**Controller.php**

```php
// /api/auth/user
public function show (Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user();
    $user->makeVisible(['email', 'email_verified_at', 'social']);
    return $user;
}
```

The `social` is a nullable json column

```php
$table->json('social')->nullable();
// 'social' => '{"facebook": "1234567890", "twitter": "1234567890"}
```

the actual HTTP response is (which I've verified in PostMan)

```json
{
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Test User",
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "social": null,
    "email_verified_at": "2022-12-27T02:50:58.000000Z",
    "created_at": "2022-12-27T02:50:58.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-12-27T02:50:58.000000Z"
}
```

---

But in the Feature Test

**tests/Feature/Auth/User/ShowTest.php**

```php
public function test_show_current_user () {
    $user = User::factory()->create();
    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get($this->api);

    $response
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJson([
            'id' => $user->id,
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'email_verified_at' => $user->email_verified_at->jsonSerialize(),
            'social' => $user->social,
        ]);
}
```

This test will always fail since it can't find `social` in the `$response`
[image]

---

Once I `dd()` the `$response`, there is no `social` attribute at all:

[image]

---

update:

My `User` model *(since so doesn't support `<details>`, I use `code snippet` to create a foldable code)*

```js
// the User model in Feature Test

App\Models\User^ {#4147 // tests/Feature/Auth/User/ShowTest.php
  #connection: "sqlite"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:8 [
    "name" => "Bettie Von"
    "email" => "lhermiston@example.net"
    "email_verified_at" => "2022-12-27 08:51:06"
    "password" => "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi"
    "remember_token" => "eMBMnyRei4"
    "updated_at" => "2022-12-27 08:51:06"
    "created_at" => "2022-12-27 08:51:06"
    "id" => 1
  ]
  #original: array:8 [
    "name" => "Bettie Von"
    "email" => "lhermiston@example.net"
    "email_verified_at" => "2022-12-27 08:51:06"
    "password" => "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi"
    "remember_token" => "eMBMnyRei4"
    "updated_at" => "2022-12-27 08:51:06"
    "created_at" => "2022-12-27 08:51:06"
    "id" => 1
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: array:2 [
    "email_verified_at" => "datetime"
    "social" => "array"
  ]
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: array:2 [
    0 => "password"
    1 => "remember_token"
  ]
  #visible: []
  #fillable: array:4 [
    0 => "name"
    1 => "email"
    2 => "password"
    3 => "social"
  ]
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
  #accessToken: null
}
```

---

Why is the `$response` in the feature test different from the actual HTTP response?

And how can I pass the feature test?

Comment: What happens when you call **$user->makeVisiable** inside of ShowTest.php

Comment: @KGG Thanks a lot for your reply. I tried to `makeVisiable` in `TestCase`, but once I `dd($user)`, the `email` and `email_verified_at` attributes are there but `social`. So I wonder if is caused by **SQLite**, since the default test database is SQLite and the type of the `social` is **json**, but once I set the test database as same as development which is **MySQL**, the `social` is still missing

Comment: Is the typo in your code or in the question only i.e. it should be `makeVisible`

Comment: @apokryfos sorry for my carelessness, it's the typo in my question instead of code

Comment: @DengSihan try the following **$user = User::factory()->create()->makeVisible(['social']);** or **$response = $this->actingAs($user->makeVisible(['social']))->get($this->api);**

Comment: May you check the $fillable in user model? can you print the array here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by adding a simple `$user->refresh();`

```php
$user = User::factory()
    ->create();

$user->refresh(); // add this

$response = $this
     ->actingAs($user)
     ->get($this->api);
```

Thanks a lot to @KGG, @apokryfos, and @Abdel-aziz hassan for their help.